# P2P vs DDNS ? What should be used?

Tags: wpf, wcf, dns, p2p, pnrp

I'm trying to build a multi-client/multi-server application
Clients includes computers, smartphones, .. etc
So they could be with static or dynamic IPs or behind firewalls or NATs .. etc
I have already implement both peer-to-peer & dynamic DNS topologies as just for enjoying coding :)
PNRP used in P2P , my implementations are as wpf/wcf services
To be honest it's my collage project
but here I stopped as a question  :
Which implementation to use ? P2P or DDNS :(
Advantages , Disadvantages & your opinions ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both approaches are valid. However DDNS is not full solution. It solves only one part of the problem, that is, matching a peer with a temporary IP address. You would still have to solve at least NAT traversal issues (see TURN and STUN solutions) and locations of peers.

There is also another issue with DNS, propagation of information is slow. When P2P exploded around Y2K, many refused to use DNS because of performance. They wanted something faster. Considering that P2P networks can be made of millions of devices changing of IP address at anytime, this would be unbearable for DNS.

On the good side, DDNS is helpful if you want to set-up a couple of stable SUPER-peers. They can be used to facilitate the organization of your P2P network.